# Doing calculations from a text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file with similar contents as below, and I want to add each column up I already have them each in an array and split and named just need to calculate the doubles

Sample file contents:

```
1,cow,2007,134.50,74.90,14.4
2,goat,2012,112.32,66.50,3.2
```

Code:

```
Livestock[] animals = new Livestock[20];
        int counter = 0;
        string myLine;
        string[] words;
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader("S:/BIT694/livestock.txt");
        while ((myLine = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            words = myLine.Split(',');
            int ID = int.Parse(words[0]);
            string LivestockType = words[1];
            int YearBorn = int.Parse(words[2]);
            double CostPerMonth = double.Parse(words[3]);
            double CostOfVaccination = double.Parse(words[4]);
            double AmountMilk = double.Parse(words[5]);


eConsole.WriteLine("Calculation of farm profit: ");
                        Console.Write("Enter price of milk: $");
                        double PriceOfMilk = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        Livestock SumOfMilk = null;
                        PriceOfMilk = PriceOfMilk * SumOfMilk.amountMilk * 365;
                        double cost = SumOfMilk.costPerMonth + SumOfMilk.costOfVaccination;
                        double total = PriceOfMilk - cost;
                            Console.WriteLine("Farm profit: ${0}", total);
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to the main menu...");
```

Comment: include the codes that you have already

Comment: What does your `Livestock` class look like? Presumably you should be adding a new instance of a `Livestock` to your `animals` array in the `while` loop, and then at the end of the loop you can get you totals.

Comment: Well, what's stopping you from calculating it?

Comment: I have a new instance but when I try to calculate it nothing shows up

Comment: You should include that code

Comment: This looks problematic: you're initializing a `Livestock` object to `null` and then trying to access properties from it? `Livestock SumOfMilk = null;
                        PriceOfMilk = PriceOfMilk * SumOfMilk.amountMilk * 365;
`

Comment: how do i fix it as it is doing my head in lol

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a new `Livestock` object in your `foreach` loop and add it to your `animals` list. Then you can just get the `Sum` of each item.

First, here's a `System.Linq` way to create a list of `Livestock` from your file:

```
List<Livestock> animals = File.ReadLines("S:/BIT694/livestock.txt")
    .Select(line => line.Split(','))
    .Select(words => new Livestock
    {
        ID = int.Parse(words[0]),
        LivestockType = words[1],
        YearBorn = int.Parse(words[2]),
        CostPerMonth = double.Parse(words[3]),
        CostOfVaccination = double.Parse(words[4]),
        AmountMilk = double.Parse(words[5])
    })
    .ToList();
```

Then you can output totals like:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Total cost per month: {animals.Sum(a => a.CostPerMonth)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Total cost of vaccinations: {animals.Sum(a => a.CostOfVaccination)}");
Console.WriteLine($"Total amount of milk: {animals.Sum(a => a.AmountMilk)}");
```

---

In case the `Linq` in the first code snippet is confusing, it's the same as:

```
List<Livestock> animals = new List<Livestock>();

foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("S:/BIT694/livestock.txt"))
{
    var words = line.Split(',');

    var animal = new Livestock
    {
        ID = int.Parse(words[0]),
        LivestockType = words[1],
        YearBorn = int.Parse(words[2]),
        CostPerMonth = double.Parse(words[3]),
        CostOfVaccination = double.Parse(words[4]),
        AmountMilk = double.Parse(words[5])
    };

    animals.Add(animal);
}
```

Comment: is there any other way that i can show my whole program so you can go over it for me?

Comment: Sure, you can edit your question with more details and try to make it more precise. It seems like the answer above is not what you were looking for - I see you're also asking the user to enter the price of milk, so you want to do some calculations on each animal, or each animal type I guess?

Comment: each animal aye but i only want it to display the total so what i have to do is the priceofmilk * the amount of milk * that by 365 and then i have to - the vaccine and the costpermonth am i making sence

Answer (score 0):

i have figured out how  to do it i hope this helps someone else

```
Console.WriteLine("Calculation of farm profit: ");
                        Console.Write("Enter price of milk: $");
                        double PriceOfMilk = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        double sumOfMilk = 0.0;
                        // loop through all livestocks (the array)
                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                        {
                            sumOfMilk += animals[i].amountMilk;
                        }// end of for loop sumOfMilk
                        double yearIncome = sumOfMilk * 365 * PriceOfMilk; // total income
                        double cost = 0.0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
                        {
                            cost += animals[i].costOfVaccination; // vaccination
                            cost += animals[i].costPerMonth * 12;
                        }// end of for loop Vaccination
                        double total = yearIncome - cost;
                        // Farms total profit for the year
                        Console.WriteLine("Farm profit: ${0}", total.ToString("0.00"));
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to return to the main menu...");
                        Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Clear();
```